# How to expose Foreign Key property to existing entity having navigational property using EF6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an entity which is already being used with an underlying database, and it was created with just the navigational property to an optional entity (1:0..1).  So by default conventions, EF created a nullable foreign key column in the DB and gave it the "MyProp_Id" name with underscore, according to that convention.

Now, I wish to expose that foreign key as a property on the entity, because it will make certain scenarios easier for me.  I don't want to rename/change the underlying foreign key column in the DB (the MyProp_Id one). In fact, there shouldn't be any underlying DB updates, I just want to expose that FK on the entity.  A code sample to clarify:

```
public class MyEntityA 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    //public long? MyOptionalEntityB_Id { get; set; }  <== this is what I am trying to add
    //public long? MyOptionalEntityBId { get; set; }  <== this didn't work either

    public MyEntityB MyOptionalEntityB { get; set; }

}
```

I've tried just simply adding the "MyOptionalEntity_Id" property as property on the entity, hoping that EF would "automagically" see that because the names are the same, it would just map and be happy.  NO DICE.

Then I tried to name my property "MyOptionalEntityId" (no underscore), but still NO DICE.

Then I tried adding an explicit mapping configuration to say:

```
this.Property(p => p.MyOptionalEntityId).HasColumnName("MyOptionalEntity_Id");
```

NO DICE

Is there a way to do this?  Is this clear and make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding [foreign key attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public long? MyOptionalEntityB_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("MyOptionalEntityB_Id")]
public MyEntityB MyOptionalEntityB { get; set; }
```

Or using [fluent api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx).

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityA >()
    .HasOptional(x => x.MyOptionalEntityB)
    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.MyOptionalEntityB_Id);
          // ^^^ -> if MyEntityB has collection of MyEntityA, mention it
```

Comment: yah, you can't id non-conventional FK names with hascolumnname

Comment: I went with option 2, as we don't use the annotations paradigm, and keep our entities just as POCOs with no EF dependencies.  Thanks!

Comment: @JulieLerman So it's impossible to both expose the FK column in my entity AND give it a custom name in the database?

Comment: @HenriqueMiranda, it's possible if you use `HasForeignKey` and `HasColumnName` together, what Julie meant, as far as my understanding was, the FK column in the entity doesn't fit [the convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), `‘<navigation property name><principal primary key property name>’, ‘<principal class name><primary key property name>’,` so it has to be configured with `ForeignKey` attribute or `HasForeignKey`

Comment: You should always use the `nameof` keyword instead of typing out property names.  That way if you rename the property, the mapping will still be correct.

Comment: So you have to manually add the property MyOptionalEntityB_Id?