# Update Entity to expose existing foreign key property in EF code first?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I tried this question: [How to expose Foreign Key property to existing entity having navigational property using EF6 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061378/how-to-expose-foreign-key-property-to-existing-entity-having-navigational-proper) and it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
The index 'IX_FormEntry_Id' is dependent on column 'FormEntry_Id'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN FormEntry_Id failed because one or more objects 
access this column.
```

I was just trying to expose the FormEntryId on the FormReport POCO:

```
public class FormReport : Entity
{
    public Guid? FormEntryId { get; set; } //I added this
    public virtual FormEntry FormEntry { get; set; }
    //other props
}
```

And I used this mapping as outlined in the above linked answer:

```
public class FormReportMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FormReport>
{
    public FormReportMapping()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.FormEntry)
        .WithOptional()
        .Map(p => p.MapKey("FormEntry_Id"));

        new EntityMap().MapInheritedProperties(this);
    }
}
```

I was hoping it would recognize hey that's exactly how it is, no change needed, but that's not what's happening, how can I do this?

Edit: I'd like to keep my naming conventions, which doesn't match the auto generated ones by EF. Not a single other of my FK properties use an underscore in my POCOs. But that's what the column name in the DB is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can easily be done with data annotations:

```
public class FormReport : Entity
{
    [Column("FormEntry_Id")]) // Map to the existing column name
    [ForeignKey("FormEntry")] // Associate with the navigation property 
    public Guid? FormEntryId { get; set; }
    public virtual FormEntry FormEntry { get; set; }
    //other props
}
```

What about fluent API, looks like the only way to achieve the goal is to emulate the above:

```
public class FormReportMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FormReport>
{
    public FormReportMapping()
    {
        Property(x => x.FormEntryId)
            .HasColumnName("FormEntry_Id")
            .HasColumnAnnotation("ForeignKey", "FormEntry");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to use the fluent API? We don't really do any attributes and all our mappings are in separate classes as above. It would be bad design to only do it with attributes in this case. From everything else I've seen the attributes have some fluent API corollary, but can't figure this one out.